# Angular $modal scope - Passing an object to $modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to pass angular's bootstrap modal the url of the image that was clicked in a angular masonry gallery. What I have is very close to the demo in the documentation with only a few changes. I know this is completely an issue with my own understanding of scope.

My modal HTML:

```
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                <a href="#" ng-click="$event.preventDefault(); selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
```

And in my Controller:

```
angular.module('testApp').controller('GalleryCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $log) {
  $scope.animationsEnabled = true;
  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
  // Temporary Generation of images to replace with about us images
  function genBrick() {
      var height = ~~(Math.random() * 500) + 100;
      var id = ~~(Math.random() * 10000);
      return {
        src: 'http://placehold.it/' + width + 'x' + height + '?' + id
      };
  };
  this.bricks = [
    genBrick(),
    genBrick(),
    genBrick(),
    genBrick(),
    genBrick(),
    genBrick()
  ];
  this.showImage = function(item){
    alert(item.src); // gives me exactly what im trying to pass to the modal
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
      templateUrl: 'views/modal.html',
      scope: $scope,
      controller: 'GalleryCtrl',
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });

  }
});
```

Lastly for clarity, this is my masonry code

```
<div masonry>
    <div class="masonry-brick" ng-repeat="brick in gallery.bricks">
        <img ng-src="{{ brick.src }}" alt="A masonry brick" ng-click="gallery.showImage(brick)">
    </div>
</div>
```

Right now this works fine to return the items objects 3 values in li tags to the modal just like in the original example. What id really like to pass into the model is the (item.src)  but no matter what i change it never seems to get passed in so that i can display it.

Comment: have you tried setting that to a $scope variable? $scope.obj = item.src;

Answer (score 0):

ok I find this strange to but try using 
item.src.toString(); 
For some reason it does not like to return integers.

Answer (score 0):

After a few more hours of working on this, I have determined my original question is confusing because some key components were entirely missing. The main problems were I had no controller for my modal, I needed to clean up the mixed use of this and $scope, and I needed to use resolve properly, which I was not. Still being new to angular, it was my understanding of the modal scope that led me astray.

What worked was, My gallery.js

```
'use strict';
/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name testApp.controller:GalleryCtrl
 * @description
 * # GalleryCtrl
 * Controller of the testApp
 */
angular.module('testApp').controller('GalleryCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

  // Temporary Generation of random images to replace with an object later
  function genBrick() {
      var height = ~~(Math.random() * 500) + 100;
      var width = 280;
      var id = ~~(Math.random() * 10000);
      return {
        src: 'http://placehold.it/' + width + 'x' + height + '?' + id
      };
  };
  //Create a dummy object full of src: urls to pull images into masonry gallery
  $scope.bricks = [
    genBrick(),genBrick(),genBrick(),genBrick(), genBrick(),genBrick(),genBrick(),genBrick(),genBrick(), genBrick(),
    genBrick()
  ];
  // End Temporary Generation of random images to replace with an object later

  $scope.showImage = function(source){
    $scope.imageClicked = source;
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      animation: true,
      templateUrl: 'views/modal.html',
      scope: $scope,
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      resolve: {
        imageToShow: function () { // imageToShow is what needs to be passed into the modal controller
          return $scope.imageClicked;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });

  }
});

angular.module('testApp').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, imageToShow) {
  $scope.image = imageToShow; // its available here because we passed it into the function and to resolve
  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

My modal.html template:

```
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal with the image you clicked!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <img ng-src="{{ image }}" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
```

And again my view

```
<div masonry>
    <div class="masonry-brick" ng-repeat="brick in bricks">
        <img ng-src="{{ brick.src }}" alt="A masonry brick" ng-click="showImage(brick.src)">
    </div>
</div>
```